# HTML Angular 8 - How to scale an img down

Tags: html, angular8

I'm creating a gallery of PDF's using the `component.html` below. It's nearly pure HTML except for the Angular `*ngFor` loop. The PDF icons are displayed, each one linking to a specific file. My problem is with the `style="width: 100%;"`, it is meant to show up to four img's before wrapping to next line. But, the side-effect is that the img's scale to a large size. If you look at the `screenshots` below, the top image was produced using `style="width: 25%;"`, the bottom one using 100%. I like the 25% size, but I want the label's to be below the image, like we see in the 100% size. The PDF image is actually 67px x 64px.

How to fix?

**component.html**

```
<div class="row">
  <div *ngFor="let doc of docs">
    <a href="#/gallery" (click)="showDoc(doc)">
      <p style="float: left; font-size: 14pt; text-align: center; width: 25%; padding-left: 10px;">
        <img src="{{doc.img}}" style="width: 100%;"><b>{{doc.lbl}}</b>
      </p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <p style="clear: both;"></p>
</div>
```

**screenshots**
[image]

Comment: are you using bootstrap library ?

Comment: Yes, I am using the bootstrap library. What I want to accomplish, may be more of an html5/css3 thing. I'd like to have the PDF icons stay at one size, no matter how large or small I make the browser window. Do you know how to do it with bootstrap? Thanks.

Comment: then you have to fix the height of the image to some px value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the below code . I have used inline CSS for the example ( you can place it to your css & use it from the there). Here I have used 50px image height you can use as per your requirements

```
style="max-width: 100%; height:50px"
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
<div *ngFor="let doc of docs" class="col-md-4">
    <a href="#/gallery" (click)="showDoc(doc)" style="float: left; font-size: 14pt; text-align: center; width: 25%; padding-left: 10px;">
      <span>
        <img src="https://techterms.com/img/lg/pdf_109.png" style="max-width: 100%; height:50px"><b style="display: block;">{{doc.lbl}}</b>
      </span>
    </a>
  </div>


</div>
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Thanks @Shivansh! That solved the problem, I appreciate your thorough answer.

Comment: Could you plz accept the answer if its solved your problem.

Comment: Oops, sorry. I clicked the up arrow, but forgot the checkmark.